# How to treat missing data involving multiple datasets

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-analysis

I'm developing a model used to predict the probability of a client changing telephone companies based on their daily usage. My dataset has information from two weeks (14 days).

My datasets include in each row:

User ID, day (number from 1 to 14), a list of 15 more values.

The problem comes from the fact that some clients don't use their telephones everyday so for each client we have a random amount of rows (from 1 to 14) depending on the days they have used their telephones. Therefore we have some missing client-day data combinations.

Removing the missing values is not an option since the data set is small and it would affect the predictive methods.

What kind of treatement could I make for this missing day values for each client?

I've tried to make a new dataset in which we have only one entry per client, there is a new value that quantifies the amount of days of telephone usage and the rest of values are a mean of all the values found on each day of the original dataset. This decreases the size of the dataset and we would have the same problem than just removing the missing values.

I've thought about adding values for the missing days for each client (using interpolation methods) but that would twist the results since that would make the dataset as if every client used their phones everyday and that would affect the predictive model.

Comment: Not sure if "missing data" is the right term here. No usage means no usage, but it's not missing.

Following this reasoning, can't you just consider that "no usage" is actually a value of 0?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @qmeeus the question in my project says: "Before starting, note that each client doesn’t use the telephone every week. Thus, some of the client-day data combinations are not provided. First, come up with a way to treat these missing values. Removing the missing values is not suggested, since the provided data set is small and it will affect your predictive models evaluation metric." There is other NaN values in the dataset but it seems to me that the quote is referring to the missing days.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi I didn't know about crossvalidated, thank you for the reference!

Comment: @JaumeBrossaOrdóñez I guess you realise that without more info on what kind of data, it's hard to help you... I took the assumption that you were working with 'the number of time someone checks his phone' in which case my answer is valid. Otherwise, you can use interpolation to infer the missing values, for example using regression for numerical data and maybe clustering if you have categorical data.